# how to pass id for get data from api with axios.post?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

I have the first two URL requests for the first page, the second to get the data of each item on the firstpage, and according to the image below in my postman, how to send the ID of each item with Axios.Post and display its data on the single page?

[how to pass id in RequestID in raw?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukdS6.jpg)

**firstPage.vue**

```
<template>
   <div class="articles">
       <h2>featured articles</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="article-container">
       <div class="article-grid" v-for="data3 in datas3" :key="data3.ContentID" >
           <router-link to="/content" @click="getContent" >
           <img :src="data3.LandscapeImage">
           <div class="article-title">
               <p>{{data3.Properties[5].Value}}</p>
               <h3>{{data3.Title}}</h3>
           </div>
           </router-link>
       </div>
   </div>
   

    <div class="number-container">
               <a class="previous" href="">&laquo; <span>previous</span></a>
               <a href="">1</a>
               <a href="">2</a>
               <a href="">3</a>
               <a href="">4</a>
               <a href="">...</a>
               <a href="">10</a>
            <a class="next" href="#"> <span>next</span> &raquo;</a>
       </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
name : "ThirdSection",
 props : ['datas3'],
}

????
</script>
```

**singlePage.vue**

```
<template>

   <div class="content">
       <div class="content-sidebar">
       <SideBar />
       </div>
       <section class="main-content">

         <div class="content-container">
             <div class="content-img"> <img src="" alt=""></div>
             <div class="content-text" >
                 <h2></h2>
                 <p></p>
             </div>
         </div>
       </section>
    
   </div>


</template>

<script>

import SideBar from '../../components/Sidebar.vue'

export default {
components :{
    SideBar
},
</script>
```

how to show data each items in single page ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know how to give the ID of each item in axios.post then send them to the API, then I can get the data for the singlepage.vue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand your question correctly, but i think you're asking how to path parameters in vue and inject them into an axios post.

You can read about [dynamic path parameters here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html). You define their key in your router file and can get them from your component using `this.$route.key`.